# is there a way to get the value from the first cell in html table row using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm trying to figure out how to get the value from the first column of selected row inside the HTML table
i'm selecting the row using button created using this js code :

```
let tr = document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");

Array.from(tr).forEach(function (trArray) {
    let button = document.createElement("i");
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    button.innerText = "";
    button.className = "fa fa-eye";
    button.style.color = "black";
    button.hidden = "hidden";
    button.onmouseover = "this.style.cursor='pointer'";
    button.onclick = "viewrow(this)";
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "viewrow(this)");
    td.append(button);
    trArray.append(td);
});
```

the table is created from code behind using stringbuilder
what I tried is this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("<table id=" + "contractstable" + " runat=" + "server" + " " + "class=" + "table" + " >");
                    sb.Append("<caption>البنود</caption>");
                    sb.Append("<thead>");
                    sb.Append("<tr>");
                    sb.Append("<th>رقم البند</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>رقم الفاتورة</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>صنف البند</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>سعر القطعة</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>القيمة</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>الخصم</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>المجموع</th>");
                    sb.Append("<th>حذف</th>");
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                    sb.Append("</thead>");
                    sb.Append("<tbody id=" + "mytbody" + ">");
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        sb.Append("<tr><td data-label=" + "رقم-البند" + ">" + dr["contract_id"]
                    + "</td><td data-label= " + "رقم-الفاتورة" + " > " + dr["bill_id"]
                    + "</td><td data-label=" + "صنف-البند" + ">" + dr["contract_category"]
                    + "</td><td data-label=" + "سعر-القطعة" + ">" + dr["item_price"]
                    + "</td><td data-label=" + "القيمة" + ">" + dr["amount"]
                    + "</td><td data-label=" + "الخصم" + ">" + dr["discount"]
                    + "</td><td data-label=" + "المجموع" + ">" + dr["total"] + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</tbody>");
                    sb.Append("</table>");
                    ltrTable.Text = sb.ToString();
```

then i want to get the selected row id , what i have tried :

```
function deleterow(element) {
    var mytbody = document.getElementById("mytbody");
    var firstchild = mytbody.querySelector("td");
    var allName = firstchild.innerText;
    var hiddentext2 = document.getElementById("myrow_id");
    hiddentext2.focus();
    hiddentext2.value = allName;
    hiddentext2.blur();
}
```

Comment: can you share your HTML structure as well

Comment: "using javascript only" ... I'm curious to know what else you *could* use in a browser

Comment: Use addEventListener for events,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the first element. If it has more than one of similar elements, it always gets the first one.

Your cell does not have value either. You should use `innerText` instead.

```js
function getrowid(element) {
  var mytbody = document.getElementById("mytbody");
  var firstchild = mytbody.querySelector("td");
  var allName = firstchild.innerText;
  console.log(allName)
}

getrowid()
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="mytbody">
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third</td>
      <td>Fourth</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: actually your method worked like a charm man !! , but i asked the wrong question , it's now updated

Comment: now it's all good for your case? Are you able to use  `getrowid`? @SalimAl-Tarsha

Comment: thanks to you i'm able to get only the first cell in table , but i want to get first cell of selected row

Comment: Could you add the code where you call `getrowid`? I can help you to integrate with it? @SalimAl-Tarsha

Comment: sorry, thats added by miskate

Comment: How do you use `element` in `deleterow(element)`? I guess it's potentially your selected row, but I haven't seen where you call it in your code @SalimAl-Tarsha

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector("#myTbale > tbody");
const tds = tbody.querySelectorAll("td");
let tdVal = [];
tds.forEach(td => {
  tdVal.push(td.innerText);
})
console.dir(tdVal[0]);
```

```html
<table border="1" id="myTbale">
  <thead>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1st cell</td>
      <td>1st cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```